# How To Determine SDK Level of Android App?

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle

I am trying to determine the Build SDK level from within my app.  I tried

```
Log.i( "MYAPP", "SDK="+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT );
```

I previously had been building for level 28, but recently upgraded to level 30.
My module's current build.gradle file included:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion      30 // was 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ramrod.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30 // was 28  
        more ...
```

*Strangely, logcat still shows level 28.*
I've re-synced, did a clean and rebuilt the app but no change.

**What's going on
?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT), SDK_INT returns the OS version of the device in which the app is running, and not the targetSdkVersion you're looking for.

> **public static final int SDK_INT**
>
> The SDK version of the software
> currently running on this hardware device.
> This value never changes
> while a device is booted, but it may increase when the hardware
> manufacturer provides an OTA update.

To get the targetSdkVersion you need to use [ApplicationInfo.targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#targetSdkVersion) class:

```
  packageManager.getApplicationInfo(youPackage, 0).targetSdkVersion;
```